# Attach to a click event in XAML control when loading XAML dynamically.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, runtime

I have a XAML control which gets loaded dynamically at runtime. This is pure XAML with no code behind.

I dont have any control over the parent loading mechanism which is why this looks a bit weird.

I have a parent application which loads my Plugin DLL and loads my XAML Control.

My DLL signature is:

```
public class Application : BaseClassHere
{
    public Application(IParentContext context) : base(context)
    {
        // Im placing this instance in the bag which i use in my XAML
        base.MyObservablePropertyBag["MyParentContext"] = new ObservableValue<object>(this);
    }
}
```

My XAML is like this:

```
<av:UserControl 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplicationNS;assembly=MyDll"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >

    <Border DataContext="{Binding MyObservablePropertyBag[MyParentContext].Value}" >

        <Button Name="MyButton" />

    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

This binding works perfectly in the XAML. I have full access to all public properties that i definein the Application class.

My problem is that i want to link to up Click events on my Buttons. If i add a Click event in the XAML it errors at runtime telling me that i need to compile my XAML.

Is there any way to subscribe to the Click event on MyButton in the Application class?

Comment: It errored when just adding an event trigger to Routed.Event click via xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you say binding works then why try to mess with the Click event? Rather go with the Button's Command property. Create an `ICommand` instance (like a `DelegateCommand` or `RelayCommand`) that you place in your propertybag and just bind to it!